# What does Pig passwd refer to?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am watching Doug Eadline Hadoop and Spark fundamentals. I am newbee to Hadoop And Pig so I am struggling to understanding this line

```
grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':'):
```

Variable 'passwd' refers to what? 
My HDP Hortonworks password or something else?
If I go for

```
grunt> DUMP A;
```

terminal output

```
2019-07-13 19:51:07,300 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/passwd
Details at logfile: /root/pig_1563047441325.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is trying to load `hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/passwd`, then this is calculated as

`fs.defaultFS` (property from `core-site.xml`) + `/user/` + `$(whoami)` (in your case, you started Pig as `root` user), then any filename.

You could get the same with `A = load '/user/root/passwd'` or `load 'hdfs:///user/root/passwd'`

Perhaps they copied `/etc/passwd` into HDFS first? Or started Pig from the `/etc` directory and started Pig using `pig -x local`, which starts Pig locally and doesn't require Hadoop cluster .